# How to get the beginning of a minute from datetime in MariaDB/MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, datetime, mariadb

I am implementing an aggregate statistics table that will contain per-minute aggregates of realtime data stored in another table. To accomplish this, I believe I need a way to get the beginning of a minute from `datetime`.

E.g. if datetime is `dt='2020-06-08 21:20:33'` , I need a function `F(dt)='2020-06-08 21:20:00'`, so that I can call it on `NOW()` in the queries.

So far I can think of the following which may be slow due to datetime-string-datetime route:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H%i00'), '%Y%m%d%H%i%S') AS MinuteBeginning
```

Could you please help with a more efficient solution, perhaps as a stored procedure? If MySQL solution differs from MariaDB, the latter is preferred.

Comment: Substract the seconds from the timestamp, in Standard SQL `current_timestamp - (extract(second from current_timestamp) * interval '1' second)`

Comment: @dnoeth, this seems wrong in case the timestamp has microseconds, doesn't it?

Comment: In Standard SQL it works as expected, the Extract includes the subsecond part, thus extract (second from time '12:34:56.7687') results in 56.7687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Y2038 is an issue, string manipulation is another option:

```
select now(), CONCAT(LEFT(NOW(), 17), '00');
+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| now()               | CONCAT(LEFT(NOW(), 17), '00') |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| 2020-06-08 23:24:59 | 2020-06-08 23:24:00           |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: The result seems to be of string type rather than datetime. Is a cast needed?

Comment: @SergeRogatch - In most contexts, no.  Strings that look like date or datetime are readily treated as such.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Unix epochs:

```
from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp() / 60) * 60)
```

Integer arithmetic should be a wee bit faster.  In an aggregation query, though, the data shuffling is usually much more expensive than other operations.